# Is there a way to create new databases within a single cluster in PostGRES for CosmosDB?

Tags: postgresql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDB instance running using the "PostGRES API for CosmosDB". Currently, my application is using the default "citus" database. I would like to create other databases on this cluster (a staging environment's dedicated database for instance), however, I am worried that there may be specific integrations with the database named "citus". Is it possible to simply create new databases within this existing cluster, or do I need a new cluster for each database when using PostGRES on Cosmos?

Comment: The Azure portal provides credentials to connect to exactly one database per cluster, the citus database. Creating another database is currently not allowed, and the CREATE DATABASE command will fail with an error.

Comment: @Rafael Kennedy Have you tried any effort which resulted in some errors or blockers?

Comment: @PratikLad thanks, that was helpful. I don't need to worry about whether there is important behavior tied to the citus database because I won't be able to create a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a way to create new databases within a single cluster in PostGRES for CosmosDB?**

**Posting it as answer to help other community members.**

According to [Microsoft Dcumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/postgresql/reference-limits#database-creation),

> The Azure portal provides credentials to connect to exactly one database per cluster, the `citus` database. **Creating another database is currently not allowed**, and the CREATE DATABASE command will fail with an error.

If you try to create another database in a single cluster, you will get a below error.

[image]

**Another option obviously is to create multiple clusters by which each cluster acts as an individual database.**

Comment: Was wondering about this as well, however was disappointing on the part for what azure is providing...